# Has anyone successed to include screenshots in mocha-junit-reporter XML files with Cucumber preprocessor?

Tags: junit, cucumber, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to generate XML Junit results to be included in Gitlab pipelines results.

So far, it is getting smoothly : I have every XML files generated, and they display as I want to in the pipeline.

However, once I try to embed the screenshots taken during the scenarios, I cannot make it work.

I started here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporter#attachments

So, I generated my cypress.json like this :

```
"mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
        "mochaFile": "cypress/reports/junit/results-[hash].xml",
        "attachments": true
    }
```

As it seems to not be automatic this, I added a `beforeEach` hook, with:

```
this.test.attachments = ['cypress/screenshots/scenario/scenario.feature/test-scr.png'];
```

If I try to set this line inside a test, and not in the hood, I have an error saying:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')"

In this folder, this file exists, but I'm not sure if I am starting at the good folder level to include it (anyway, I tried several possibilities, never got it to work).

I never get to have this new tag :

```
<system-out>[[ATTACHMENT|path/to/file]]</system-out>
```

I get the feeling that there is kind of a different way of working with the cucumber preprocessor, as we don't write between *describe* and *it* anymore, but I have no proof o that.

What am I missing ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the exact same issue and can't seem to find good guides to it anywhere online.

Comment: I'm struggling with this at the moment also.

Answer (score 0):

In your spec file, don't use arrow functions if you want to use `this`.

Arrow functions, unlike regular function declarations, don't redefine `this`.

Replace this

```
it('should pass'), () => {
    // your code
}
```

with this

```
it('should pass'), function () {
    // your code
}
```